# HTML form fields and margin display

Tags: html, css

I am designing HTML form, but I am facing two problems.
The first problem is that when I click inside the text field, the value text does not disappear.

The second thing is that I want to display the form in the bottom left corner of the screen, like you were sitting infront of a computer, and dragged the mouse down to the bottom left corner of the screen (with your right hand).
[The link for the form is given](http://mrprofessional.se/facebook/)

Code for the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Add PHP Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
#formwrapper{
width:340px;
border:0;
background-color:#dce37f;
margin: 70px auto;
padding: 20px 0;
display:block;
}
#headdiv{
width:340px;
border:0;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 18.5px;
}
form {
display:block;
width:340px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.text{
width: 275px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 18.5px;
}
.text:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
.fname{
display: inline;
width: 116px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 18.5px;
}
.fname:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
.lname{
display: inline;
width: 116px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 1px;
}
.lname:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
.gatadress{
display: inline;
width: 116px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 18.5px;
}
.gatadress:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
.postnr{
display: inline;
width: 116px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 1px;
}
.postnr:focus{
outline: none;
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
#Jag{
display: inline;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 22px;

}
.label{

padding:0px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="formwrapper">
<div id="headdiv">
<img src="original_hembakat_besta_ll.png" />
</div>
<form id="demo-form" parsley-validate>

    <input type="email" name="email" value= "E-Post*" parsley-trigger="change" required class="text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value= "Fornamn*" required size="18px" class="fname" />
     <input type="text" name="lastname" value= "Efternamn*" required size="18px" class="lname" /><br/>
     <input type="text" name="telephone" value= "Telefon*" required size="43px" class="text" /><br/>
     <input type="text" name="gatuadress" value= "Gatuadress*" required size="43px" class="gatadress"/>
     <input type="text" name="postnr" value= "Postnr*" required size="43px" class="postnr"/><br/>
     <input type="text" name="postort" value= "Postort*" required size="43px" class="text" /><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="Jag" value = "Jag godkänner villkoren" />
     <label for = "jaggod" class="label">Jag godkanner <a href="https://a.pgtb.me/facebook/app/139383/renderi/#">villkoren</a></label><br/>

     <input type="submit" value="Send" />


</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first of the two problems can be solved with the 'placeholder' attribute. Use that instead of 'value':

```
<input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Telefon*" required size="43px" class="text" />
```

I don't understand what the second problem is.

Comment: It should be noted that this makes the form unusable in IE9 and below that don't support placeholders and thus just show a bunch of empty fields.

Comment: This is true; for accessibility he should also add <label> tags.

Comment: nice, it now look more nice but still there/

Answer (score 1):

For placeholders, [use placeholders](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder), like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name">
```

This is considered bad design practice though, since you're making the usability of the form depend on whether there's data in there - if someone puts crap inside it, they have no way to find out what the field was originally for, which is a Bad Idea(tm) from a user experience perspective. Also, placeholders don't work in IE<=9.

You can emulate a simple placeholder with [some simple Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/889DS/), like:

```
<input type="text" value="placeholder" onfocus="undoPlaceholder(this)">
```

And JS:

```
function undoPlaceholder(e)
{
    if(e.undone) return;
    e.undone = true;
    e.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the text actually disappear when you click in the box, and re-appear when you click out, use this:

```
<input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Telefon*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='Telefon*'" required size="43px" class="text" />
```

As far as the 2nd question, I too am confused.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/J6kHa/

Answer (score 0):

For the placing form on the right bottom put this styles for the form wrapper

```
#formwrapper {
width: 340px;
border: 0;
background-color: #dce37f;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```